# Split String in java by specified pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, split

**How to split this String in java such that I'll get the text occurring between the braces in a String array?**

```
GivenString = "(1,2,3,4,@) (a,s,3,4,5) (22,324,#$%) (123,3def,f34rf,4fe) (32)"

String [] array = GivenString.split("");
```

**Output** must be:

```
array[0] = "1,2,3,4,@"
array[1] = "a,s,3,4,5"
array[2] = "22,324,#$%"
array[3] = "123,3def,f34rf,4fe"
array[4] = "32"
```

Comment: Use this pattern [`"\\((.*?)\\)"`](https://regex101.com/r/dL9yH9/1). Then `$1` is containing what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
Matcher mtc = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(yourString);
```

Comment: Use: `while (mtc.find()) { String match = mtc.group(1); /* ... */ }`.

Comment: For performance, instead of a reluctant quantifier (`*?`), use a greedy quantifier that cannot match close-parenthesis: `"\\(([^)]*)\\)"`

Comment: Can I find number of items the matcher (mtc) contains without using the while loop (or any loop)? In order to the define the size of the String array.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is the [answer by Rahul Tripathi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37212012/5221149), but your question said *"How to **split**"*, so if you must use `split()` (e.g. this is an assignment), then this regex will do:

```
^\s*\(|\)\s*\(|\)\s*$
```

It says:

- Match the open-parenthesis at the beginning
- Match close-parenthesis followed by open-parenthesis
- Match the close-parenthesis at the end

All 3 allowing whitespace.

As a Java regex, that would mean:

```
str.split("^\\s*\\(|\\)\\s*\\(|\\)\\s*$")
```

See [regex101 for demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB9vT1/1).

The problem with using `split()` is that the leading open-parenthesis causes a split before the first value, resulting in an empty value at the beginning:

```
array[0] = ""
array[1] = "1,2,3,4,@"
array[2] = "a,s,3,4,5"
array[3] = "22,324,#$%"
array[4] = "123,3def,f34rf,4fe"
array[5] = "32"
```

That is why Rahul's answer is better, because it won't see such an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would want to use the split() function as this is the easiest way to split a string into multiple arrays when the string is broken up by a key char.

The main problem is that you need information *inbetween* two chars.  The easiest way to solve this problem would to go through the string get ride of every instance of '('.  This leaves the string looking like

String =  "1,2,3,4,@) a,s,3,4,5) 22,324,#$%) 123,3def,f34rf,4fe) 32)"

And this is perfect, as you can split by the char ')' and not worry about the other bracket interfering with the split. I suggest using the replace("","") where it replaces every instance of the first parameter with the second parameter (we can use "" to delete it).

Here is some example code that may work :

```
String a = "(1,2,3,4,@) (a,s,3,4,5) (22,324,#$%) (123,3def,f34rf,4fe) (32)" 
a = a.replace("(","");
//a is now equal to 1,2,3,4,@) a,s,3,4,5) 22,324,#$%) 123,3def,f34rf,4fe) 32)
String[] parts = a.split("\\)");

System.out.println(parts[0]); //this will print 1,2,3,4,@
```

I haven't tested it completely, so you may end up with unwanted spaces at the end of the strings you may need to get rid of!

You can then loop through parts[] and it should have all of the required parts for you!